# Tap on a text field not displaying the date picker embedded in monkeytalk

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to automate our iOS application where a date picker component will get displayed on tapping a text field(input component).

While recording with monkey talk, it records both tap on the text field and date selection from date picker component.

While playing back, script completes successfully (as shown in monkeytalk console) but tap on the text field operation is not displaying the date picker.